# stop closing showDialogue itself after 15 seconds

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, async-await

I am trying to display an information dialog when starting an application. After closing, another window appears asking for permission. I call it all in the initState function. It works, but I noticed that this first info dialog also closes on its own when 15 seconds have elapsed. How do I fix this? So that while the dialog is not closed by the user, the application will not be loaded further?

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
final keyIsFirstLoaded = 'is_first_loaded';
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
      final context = MyApp.navKey.currentState.overlay.context;
       await showDialogIfFirstLoaded(context);
       await initPlatformState();
    });
  }
showDialogIfFirstLoaded(BuildContext context, prefs) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    bool isFirstLoaded = prefs.getBool(keyIsFirstLoaded);
    if (isFirstLoaded == null) {
      return showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          // return object of type Dialog
           return new AlertDialog(
                 // title: new Text("title"),
                 content: new Text("//"),
                 actions: <Widget>[
                  new FlatButton(
                    child: new Text(".."),
                    onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  prefs.setBool(keyIsFirstLoaded, false);
                },
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      );
    }
  }
initPlatformState() async {
    print('Initializing...');
    await BackgroundLocator.initialize();
    print('Initialization done');
    final _isRunning = await BackgroundLocator.isRegisterLocationUpdate();
    setState(() {
      isRunning = _isRunning;
    });
    onStart();
    print('Running ${isRunning.toString()}');
  }
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      localizationsDelegates: [
        // ... app-specific localization delegate[s] here
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      navigatorKey:MyApp.navKey,
      navigatorObservers: [
        FirebaseAnalyticsObserver(analytics: analytics),
      ],
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: '',
      theme: ThemeData(),
      home: new SplashScreen(),}
class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SplashScreenState createState() => new _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  Timer _timer;
  bool _visible = true;
  startTime() async {  
      _timer = Timer(new Duration(seconds: 5), navigationPage); 
  }
  void navigationPage() {
    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/home');
  }
  @override
  void initState() {
    _timer = Timer(Duration(seconds: 4),
          () => setState(
            () {
          _visible = !_visible;
        },
      ),
    );
    startTime();
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  void dispose() {
    _timer.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          child: Image.asset('images/bg.jpg',
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            height: 1200,
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          height: 1200,
          color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.8),
        ),
        Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                flex: 2,
                child: Container(
                  child: Text(''),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `showDialogIfFirstLoaded` used to display first dialog?

Comment: @JohnJoe yes, he shows the popup with info

Comment: try ```Navigator.pop(context)``` instead of ```Navigator.of(context).pop()``` in the alert dialog

Comment: @NishuthanS it isnt work

Answer (score 1):

This code displays an Alert dialogue if the user is new and after the button click, it will direct him to another dialogue.

I have tested the code and it doesn't close after 15 seconds. I'm still not sure what you're trying to accomplish but I hope this helps.

Init State

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
      await dialog1(context);
      //await initPlatformState();
    });
    super.initState();
  }
```

Alert Dialog 1

```
dialog1(BuildContext context)async{
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    bool isFirstLoaded = prefs.getBool("keyIsFirstLoaded")??true;

    if (isFirstLoaded) {
      showDialog(
        barrierDismissible: false, //disables user from dismissing the dialog by clicking out of the dialog
        context: context, builder: (ctx) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text("dialog 1"), content: Text("Content"), actions: [
            TextButton(
            child: new Text(".."),
            onPressed: () async{
            Navigator.pop(ctx);
            await dialog2(context);
            prefs.setBool("keyIsFirstLoaded", false);
          },
        ),],);
      },);
    }else{
      //not first time
    }
  }
```

Alert Dialog 2

```
void dialog2(BuildContext context)async{
    print("dialog 2");
    showDialog(context: context, builder: (context) {
      return AlertDialog(title: Text("Dialog 2"),content: Text("permissions"),actions: [
        TextButton(
        child: new Text("close"),
        onPressed: () async{
          Navigator.pop(context);
          //await dialog1(context); //uncomment if you want to go back to dialoge 1
        },
      ),],);
    },);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return a value from `Navigator` in the first dialog

```
Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
prefs.setBool(keyIsFirstLoaded, false);
```

Once it receive true, then only call the second method.

```
var value = await showDialogIfFirstLoaded(context);
if(value == true) {
   await initPlatformState();
}
```

Comment: its not working. The firts popup still disappears, and the second popup does not even appear

Comment: how about add  `barrierDismissible: false`, in `showDialog` ?

Comment: its also didnt help

Comment: as i understand when the first screen loads, the popup disappears

Comment: not really get your question..When the first dialog will shown? When first screen loads, first dialog disappears ? Can you paste the code for first screen?

Comment: Edited the code. When I open my application, a popup(showDialogIfFirstLoaded(context)) appears with information, when I click on it on the button Next, another popup(initPlatformState()) appears with a request for permission. This is normal application behavior. This is how it works now. But there is a bug that when I load the application and the first popup appears and I will not press anything, but just wait, it will disappear by itself after about 15 seconds and another popup and the loaded first page will appear

Comment: so after 15 sec `Initializing...` printing?

Comment: it doesn't work. the next screen starts and the popup disappear(the next popup with permission doesnt show)